# Convert ArrayList to byte array

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I have a code where I am converting array list to byte array and then saving that byte array as a BLOB in MySQL database. Below is code:-

```
Object temp = attributes.get(columnName);
if (temp instanceof List && temp != null) {
    List extraAttributes = (ArrayList) temp;
    resultStmt.setBytes(currentIndex, createByteArray(extraAttributes));
```

The method `createByteArray` is defined as below:

```
 private byte [] createByteArray( Object obj)
    {
        byte [] bArray = null;
        try
        {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream objOstream = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                objOstream.writeObject(obj);
                bArray = baos.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
      TraceDbLog.writeError("Problem in createByteArray", e);

        }

                return bArray;

    }
```

Well the above code was written earlier for writing HashMap to BLOB i am using same for converting ArrayList if HashMap to BLOB.

The problem which is occurring in read code when i am reading the blob.

```
 private Object readBytes (ResultSet rs, String columnName)
    throws SQLException
    {
        ObjectInputStream ois  = null;
        byte [] newArray;
        Object obj = null;

        try
        {
            newArray = rs.getBytes(columnName);

            ois = new ObjectInputStream (new ByteArrayInputStream(newArray));
            obj = ois.readObject ();
        }
```

In the read part the object is not coming as arrayList of hasMap and in debug perspective in eclipse eclipse is also not able to inspect the object which is coming.

I have also tried typecasting the object to List but still no success in getting the right response.
Please tell me whether there is any flaw in reading/writing the above BLOB.

Comment: what object r u getting after read object? what is it printing if u do System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName())

Comment: Its showing com.sun.jdi.InvocationtargetException which means eclipse cant resolve. Although this exception is coming in debug perspective there is no point when code moves into catch block the program execution is normal

Comment: is obj = ois.readObject (); failing when u execute the code ? if it's not failing what type of object is it returning

Comment: IN logs i printed obj.getClass().getName() its returning java.util.ArrayList

Comment: So read object is returning an ArrayList as expected. What is the exact issue you are facing ? Is the data inside the list not what u expect ?

Comment: yes basically thats the main issue data inside array list is not as expected. I am basically creating array list of hash map but its returning arraylist with incorrect hash maps when viewed. Its a very strange issue i guess there is some problem in converting it into object.  The array list is getting converted into byte array but i guess its members i.e. hash maps are not getting converted into byte array in proper manner somewhat like deepcopy and shallow copy thing  i believe.  DO i need to change the conversion logic so as to ensure entire object is converted into byte array

Comment: if the objects inside the hashmap are also serialized. when you use ObjectOutputStream those two will get converted to byte[].

Comment: There are all Strings inside HashMaps which implements Serializable so in that case those should get converted to byte[].  Are there and restrictions on strings being converted into byte[] . I mean to say any loopholes in byte[] conversion.

Comment: Someone please solve my problem i cant get any clue why this erratic behavior is there in case of conversion to byteArray?

Answer (score 5):

I have added sample coding for convert **ArrayList to byte[]**.

One reasonable way would be to use UTF-8 encoding like DataOutputStream does for each string in the list. For a string it writes 2 bytes for the length of the UTF-8 encoding followed by the UTF-8 bytes.

This would be portable if you're not using Java on the other end. Here's an example of encoding and decoding an ArrayList:

```
// example input list
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("foo");
list.add("bar");
list.add("baz");

// write to byte array
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);

for (String element : list) {
    out.writeUTF(element);
}
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

// read from byte array
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(bais);
while (in.available() > 0) {
    String element = in.readUTF();
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Comment: Just in case the built-in bytes need to be parsed using an xml unmarshaller, the encoding schemes need to be matched. In my case, it was not in UTF-8, so I just have to use out.writeBytes instead of out.writeUTF. Or else, the marshaller would throw up exception saying that unexpected content appears in the prolog. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert it to json string and then to bytes

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Alarm>>() {}.getType();
String json = gson.toJson(list, type);
byte[] bytes = json.getBytes();
```